# Bluemix - How to tell the current stack of my app?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

On September I received an email saying that the old stack (`lucid64`) will be removed by the end of October.
The email also said that on Oct 17 (three days ago) Bluemix will initiate an automatic migration to `cflinuxfs2`.
How do I know if my app was already migrated?
Do I have to run `cf push` with the `-s cflinuxfs2` flag from now on? If yes, until when?

I have executed `cf push` several times this month but without the `-s` flag.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cf app APP_NAME` should show you the stack, e.g.:

```
$ cf app APP_NAME
Showing health and status for app APP_NAME in org ORG_NAME / space SPACE_NAME as ME@MY_DOMAIN.com...
OK

requested state: started
instances: 2/2
usage: 32M x 2 instances
urls: APP_NAME.APP_DOMAIN.com
last uploaded: Mon Oct 19 02:21:39 UTC 2015
stack: cflinuxfs2
buildpack: go_buildpack

     state     since                    cpu    memory         disk           details
#0   running   2015-10-18 07:22:08 PM   2.1%   10.7M of 32M   38.9M of 64M
#1   running   2015-10-18 07:22:07 PM   2.1%   8.4M of 32M    38.9M of 64M
```

You can see it says `stack: cflinuxfs2`

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command will show you your application stack.

```
[07:40:10 ~]$ cf app velocityapp
...
stack: cflinuxfs2
```

You can re-push your application with the *-s* flag or the platform will automatically migrate you at a later date.